# jQuery UI datepicker onbeforeshow dateformat

Tags: jquery, datepicker, date-format

I'm linking an array of events which are click-able on my date picker calendar. My date format is working correctly (it's dd-mm-yy) for the `onSelect` function. So i can click and read the activity on 08/06/2013 (so that the eight of June 2013) on the calendar.

The `beforeshowday` function on the other hand, which assigns a class 'highlight' to the element uses the  wrong date format (it switches dd & mm). So the highlighted `td`'s on the calendar are displayed in the wrong months instead of the click-able and working activity `td`'s.

Please see my code:

```
var acts = [
    { Title: "En we doen eki wild", Date: new Date("08/06/2013"), Description: "Beschrijving van deze activiteit komt hier te staan" },
    { Title: "Zotte petanque!", Date: new Date("10/06/2013"), Description: ".. en van deze hier" },
    { Title: "Les :-(", Date: new Date("11/06/2013"), Description: "Beschrijving van activiteit" }
];

$("#cal").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var result = [true, '', null];
        var matching = $.grep(acts, function (event) {
            return event.Date.valueOf() === date.valueOf();
        });

        if (matching.length) {
            result = [true, 'highlight', null];
        }
        return result;
    },
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
        var date,
            selectedDate = new Date(dateText),
            i = 0,
            event = null;

        while (i < acts.length && !event) {
            date = acts[i].Date;

            if (selectedDate.valueOf() === date.valueOf()) {
                event = acts[i];
            }
            i++;
        }
        if (event) {
            $("#acts h3").html(event.Title);
            $("#acts h4").html(event.Date);
            $("#acts .maintext").html(event.Description);
        }
    },
    minDate: 1,

});
```

Does anybody have an idea how i should fix this?
Thanks!

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/JT3hp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think javascript parser understands new Date("08/06/2013") format.
Make a new parse function to parse that correctly:

```
...
{ Title: "En we doen eki wild", Date: parseDate("08/06/2013"), Description: "Beschrijving van deze activiteit komt hier te staan" },
...

// parse a date in dd-mm-yyyy format
function parseDate(input) {
  var parts = input.match(/(\d+)/g);
  return new Date(parts[2], parts[1]-1, parts[0]);
}
```

There also was a problem for me with the valueOf() method.

```
    var matching = $.grep(acts, function (event) {
        return event.Date.toString() === date.toString();
    });

    ...

        if (selectedDate.toString() === date.toString()) {
           event = acts[i];
        }

    ...
```

Also I think javascript parser fails with dd-mm-yy in onSelect so you need to parse it manually there again.

Here's the fiddle, tested with IE, Chrome and Firefox:

http://jsfiddle.net/JT3hp/6/

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you for your fine suggestions and edits, helps me a lot!

Comment: Wait, i just saw that when using getDate() instead of valueOf(), those three events get repeated every month. With valueOf(), it doesn't work, but they don't repeat either.

Comment: Oops, ment getTime() instead of getDate(), I always confuse those two :( getDate returns current day of the month while getTime returns full date. There still something wrong with it though.

Comment: Hehe, thanks again, but now the onSelect event doesn't work :( Now, the three dates are correctly highlighted (and only in june), but clicking them doesn't show the activity..

Comment: Alright, I ended up comparing strings after all. I also switched datetimepicker constructor back to same format as the original string (dd-mm-yy) and use parseDate method to parse dateText in onSelected. If there ever occurs problems with comparing the strings consider using toLocaleString() or toString(format).

Comment: Great! You've been of great help!